# Google Analytics - track customer account creation

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get my head around custom tracking in Google Analytics. Can somebody tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible please?

I want to track when customers create an account and then have their account number show in GA so we can then track any payments they make back to the correct source / keywords at a later date. It can take weeks or even months for customers to pay, and often payment is made via bank transfer or by a different user, so relying on GA directly for that info is impractical.

What we can track is when they set up an account. When they fill in the form on our site they choose a username and are also assigned a customer number by us. Can I pass this username / ID into the information collected by GA, so as well as registering a goal completion (account sign up) it also tells me who that customer is. I can then record the keyword / source data against that account, and when they pay later on I can look it up and manually connect the two.

Hope that's clear. If not I'll try and explain it better.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Matt

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

collecting info that identifies a user is against Googles TOS, so no, you can't do this. But you can solve the problem the other way around - you can read source and medium from GA (for example by reading the Analytics cookie in ga.js, analytics.js provides some functions to get campaign info) and store it together with the user information on your own server when your visitor creates her/his account.

This will not work with auto-tagged adwords campaigns since they transmit a cryptic gclid (google click id) instead of campaign parameters. A possible workaround would be to track account creation with Analytics Ecommerce Tracking, store the Transaction Id with the account info, pull a report from GA that matches Transaction IDs and Source/Medium and match that with you local data (for this to work the adwords account needs to be linked to the Analytics account).

Comment: Great, thanks Eike. That makes sense. Not even come across the Analytics Ecommerce Tracking yet so will investigate. Really appreciate your help, enjoy your weekend.